# How to find out if an option is of american or european style?

Tags: trading, options

I am pretty new to Options. How can I find out if an offered option is of "american" or "european" style?

Can I assume that an option which is traded e.g. at EUREX is of european style?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures and equity options are American style. Index options are European.  Go to the EUREX web site for verification.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in the term sheet for the option.  Looking at [this presentation](http://www.eurexchange.com/blob/850370/55f07011f651782046df8621927f1a85/data/presentation_eurex-equity-options-oct2017.pdf) on the EUREX site, they explicitly identify their European options, so others can probably be assumed to be American style.

However, read all of the term sheets and agreements when placing a trade to be certain.